# Why is syncroning taking forever on BitcoinCore

Tags: bitcoin-core

It has been synchronizing for months and i want my money now. I have tried re-downloading , clearing cache

---

i downloading from their website. It is the lastes.t version of Bitcoin Core.Windows 10 ,4.00GB  64 Bit

Comment: Please provide some extra information. What version of Bitcoin Core, what hardware are you running on, what configuration, what operating system, ...

Comment: Where exactly did you download bitcoin-core from?

Answer (score -2):

It depends of your internet speed as the QT has to download the data. I would suggest using electrum if you dont want to download everything.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it is false: the bottleneck for synchronization generally is in verifying the complete blockchain data, not in downloading it.